# remove/add filter to Wordpress Function fil

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue trying to change the output of a message via my themes functions.php file.

Here is tbe code provided by the woocommerce plugin:

```
function woocommerce_add_to_cart_message() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') :

        $return_to  = (wp_get_referer()) ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );

    else :

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('cart')), __('View Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );

    endif;

    $woocommerce->add_message( apply_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', $message) );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is change the button message, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

I've been reading the WP codex, but unfortunately I don't think I quite understand how this works. Here's what I've tried:

```
function remove_woocommerce_add_to_cart_message() {
    remove_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', $message) ;
}

function woocommerce_add_to_cart_message_edited() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') :

        $return_to  = (wp_get_referer()) ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );

    else :

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('cart')), __('NEW CART MESSAGE', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );

    endif;

    $woocommerce->add_message( apply_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', $message) );
}
```

So, I've tried removing the filter that outputs the message, then I declare it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated it!

Comment: Are you calling your functions anywhere?

Comment: I guess not? I'm really not sure. The theme is set up with a bunch of hooks, so I need to tie into their functions. That's what I was trying to do with removing the filter. But I'm obviously not doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code states `apply_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', $message)` the code will look for any filter that is added to that hook, and go through them one at a time.

You can create a function, named whatever you like, and add it to that hook like so:

```
function my_filer_function( $message )
{
    // Here you should modify $message as you want, and then return it.
    $newButtonString = 'NEW BUTTON STRING';
    $replaceString = '<a$1class="button">' . $newButtonString .'</a>';
    $message = preg_replace('#<a(.*?)class="button">(.*?)</a>#', $replaceString, $message);
    return $message;
}
// Then add the function to that filter hook and prioritize it last
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', 'my_filer_function', 999);
```

Comment: that didn't exactly work as I was hoping. This changes the area that says "Product Successfully added to cart" - what I want to change specifically is the button text - The one that says "View Cart" - so what I did was just copy that entire variable of "message" from the previous function, and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great. You can also do something like the edited code above if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Output success messages
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :

        $return_to  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );


$message    = sprintf('%s',$added_text);
    else :


$message    = sprintf('%s',$added_text);

    endif;
```

***the above code I have made changes in it please check may be it is helpful to you***